# jquery keydown preventDefault not working on Android 4.x

Tags: javascript, android, preventdefault

This works fine on desktop in all browsers and all iOS on iPhone, but doesn't work on Android 4.x:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').keydown(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
    });
});
```

I've also tried using `keypress` and `keyup` but they also do not work (wouldnt expect `keyup` to)

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Pcf/2/

When I type, letters appear in the textbox. occasionally they will disappear randomly after I've type a few chars, but this is unpredictable (seems to occur more often on 4.1.2).

Whats going on?

I've tested this with jQuery 1.9.1 and 2.0.3 on Android 4.1.2, 4.3 and 4.4 and it doesn't work on any. 
It seems to work in the stock browser on Android 2.3.6.

What do?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have you got some solution to this problem?